# Android custom app bar underneath system default

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My MainActivity.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_appbar"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_appbar_drawer" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My intention is to have an appbar with navigation drawer (icon on left), and options menu (icon on right). However, it appears to be stuck underneath the system default. Here is an image showing its preview:

[image: Android Studio Preview]

Additionally, my styles.xml is:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**Changing AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to NoActionBar has no effect**. The appbar with "AppName" just remains above the other appbar (which should show "BEEP" as text, in addition to the two icons for navbar and options menu) - NoActionBar is also defined in the manifest for the activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="BEEP"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the relevant part of the MainActivity.java, if needed:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
...
```

So, how can I get the toolbar (ID is "toolbar") to display instead of the default appbar that currently contains the text "AppName" in the above image? I also followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html), however there is no change in the result.

EDIT 1: The following screenshot shows my user-defined appbar appearing underneath the default, for some reason. I have also included my app_bar_appbar.xml

[image: The appbar named "BEEP" is underneath and can be seen when pulled down, but when scrolling up it is hidden beneath the tab/toolbar.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_appbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want only one toolbar with all options (drawer icon and other menu on righ side) ?

Comment: Will you pls add this `@layout/app_bar_appbar` layout in your question? Also, screen with your expectation?

Comment: @AmrutBidri I have added the layout now. The layout is as shown in Dipali's solution - navbar to the left, options bar on the right. Currently, it is being masked by the default, possibly stemming from the tabview present too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are having `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to your `Application` tag of AndroidManifest all activity will include default actionbar.

Create one more theme in your styles.xml with  `NoActionBar` and apply this to your `NavigationDrawerActivity`.

**i.e.**

```
<style name="navigation_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Set it to your Navigation Activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".NavigationDrawerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer"
            android:theme="@style/navigationtheme" />
```

[image: Example of default theme with ActionBar and NavigationDrawerActivity with Different theme]

<sub>Example of default theme with ActionBar and NavigationDrawerActivity with NoActionBar theme</sub>

**EDIT**

> As @Talisman said, it was the issue with the TabLayout and ViewPager
>   of DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.and.NavigationDrawerActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--Your content in this FrameLayout-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.and.NavigationDrawerActivity">

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now Set the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in other Fragment and Load that fragment in this `FrameLayout` on `onCreate` method of `NavigationDrawerActivity`

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
        tr.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        tr.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

<sub>where fragment is other fragment which contains your TabLayout and ViewPager.</sub>

Comment: I have followed this however it only succeeds in reverting the color scheme. It looks like the default toolbar appears on top of mine for some reason. I'll edit the OP with screenshots.

Comment: @Talisman, Are you still able to see this default toolbar in preview for this `NoActionBar theme` to Activity?

Comment: No, I have the render problem "Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme"

Comment: The TabLayout forms the split between the 3 different pages, then the navigation drawer should swipe-in from the left, and options menu at the top right (as seen in your existing answer). Ideally, the TabLayout is just below the appbar.

Comment: Sorry yes, it's all a single Activity with the 3 pages being individual fragments.

Comment: My Question is : **Do you want viewpager and Tablayout in all pages ?** as your `viewpager is having match_parent` height where will you load the content from Navigation?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: The three tabs are just static pages. Assume the tabs each have a single label, such as "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3" and I will adapt later.

Comment: I awarded bounty to this given it was the most instrumental in resolving the issue, but this answer alone was not the solution in its entirety. It ultimately came down to disabling the user-defined appbar, clearing everything out, and adding each component individually again.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is looking perfect as it should be. If you just want to change the title of toolbar then you just have to add few lines of code in MainActivity.java

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
// add few lines here like...
    toolbar.setTitle("Your title here");
// ....   
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

If right option menu not showing then override these two method in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


       return false;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all select "AppTheme" from layout preview

[image]

Select Project Theme >> AppTheme.NoActionBar

[image]

To create option menu for your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.menu_item:
          //do need full stuff
        break;

        case R.id.menu_settings:
          //do need full stuff
        break;

    }

}
```

create a menu.xml in res>menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:title="Item"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />
</menu>
```